# show image field twice with different image style

Tags: media

In my content type, I am using an image field.

But in display, I want to show this image twice. Once with large style, and another with medium.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you have [Display Suite](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4ovLai-HMAhVkLMAKHb9nDJIQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fds&usg=AFQjCNHxvziCANGsu97VzD0MKZG3ccNcNw&sig2=y1WNlgvspin0xUd3A9Oncg) installed then this https://www.drupal.org/node/1246270 else you will have to clone in node preprocess and adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're displaying your field programmatically you've to use: 
For Large :

```
<?php echo theme('image_style', array(
    'style_name' => 'large',
    'path' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'],
    'alt' => t('Image'),
    'title' => t('Title'))); ?>
```

For Medium :

```
<?php echo theme('image_style', array(
    'style_name' => 'medium',
    'path' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'],
    'alt' => t('Image'),
    'title' => t('Title'))); ?>
```

Your can also call any format you added on back office his name